# Filter a list based on a multiple options

Tags: c#, linq

I want to return a list of files from a folder, based on a specific file extension.

At the moment, I get all files. How do I filter out certain types?

At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
public static List<FileInfo> BuildListOfFiles()
{
    var d = new DirectoryInfo(Constants.FolderToMonitor);
    if (d.Exists)
    {
        var files = (from file in d.EnumerateFiles() select file).ToList();
        return files;
    }
    return null;

}
```

But I only want

> *.mp4, *.mpg, *.avi, *.mpeg

I think I need another .Where, but not sure how to handle multiple types cleanly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Linq to do the filtering:

```
var searchExtensions = new string[] { ".mp4", ".mpg", ".avi", ".mpeg" };
var files = d.EnumerateFiles()
             .Where(f => searchExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file))
             .ToList();
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var searchExtensions = new string[] { ".mp4", ".mpg", ".avi", ".mpeg" };
var files = 
    (from file in d.EnumerateFiles()
     where searchExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file))
     select file)
    .ToList();
```

An alternative solution would be to build up your file list rather than filtering it:

```
var searchPatterns = new string[] { "*.mp4", "*.mpg", "*.avi", "*.mpeg" };
var files = searchPatterns.SelectMany(p => d.EnumerateFiles(p))
                          .ToList();
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var searchPatterns = new string[] { "*.mp4", "*.mpg", "*.avi", "*.mpeg" };
var files = 
    (from pattern in searchPatterns
     from file in d.EnumerateFiles(pattern))
     select file)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried this way:

```
    List<FileInfo> mediaFiles = new List<FileInfo>();

    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
    {
        FileInfo matchFiles = new FileInfo(file);

        if ((matchFiles.Extension == ".mp4") || (matchFiles.Extension == ".mpg") || (matchFiles.Extension == ".avi") || (matchFiles.Extension == ".mpeg"))
        {
            mediaFiles.Add(matchFiles);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using `GetFiles()` function too

```
var files = d.GetFiles("*.mp4|*.mpg|*.avi|*.mpeg", SearchOptions.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

Comment: My first thought was to use semi-colons, but that didn't seem to work. I tried pipes as you suggested and got "*ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.*"

Comment: Like @p.s.w.g said, this throws an exception.  The [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles) states "This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal path and wildcard (* and ?) characters, but it doesn't support regular expressions."  `|` does not meet that criteria because it is a regex operator _and_ also returned by [`Path.GetInvalidPathChars()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars).  Also, the enumeration is [`SearchOption`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.searchoption) with no `s`.