# How to filter with multiple strings in c#

Tags: c#

I'm getting list of strings from a method and split like this

```
string allports = getPorts(destin); // this like "MED SAU ABU KLA USE"
var vvk = allports.Split(' ');// this has now 5 objects
```

Now I want to filter with all above and get all data at onece. I know how to filter for one like this

```
var allResult = mainFaires.Where(d => d.port == "MED");
```

but I want to do this for all **5** objects at once and get all data at once.how can I do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter a list based on a multiple options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228929/filter-a-list-based-on-a-multiple-options)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about

```
var allResult = mainFaires.Where(d => vvk.Contains(d.port));
```